# Can not see event in Nifi data provenance?

Tags: apache-nifi

As following pic,any provenance events can not be found after runing the processors.There is no filter applied to the UI provenance search to hide provenance events.

Nifi-1.10.0/Cluster

Guessing the problem is the interval which is 0?!

[image]

The configured file is not change.
[image]